# Listen to another message only when I am done with my current message in Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am building a Springboot application using Spring Kafka where I am getting messages from a topic. I have to modify those messages and then produce them to another topic. I don't want to consume any other message till I have processed my current one. How can I achieve this?

```
@KafkaListener(
            topics = "${event.topic.name}",
            groupId = "${event.topic.group.id}",
            containerFactory = "eventKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
public void consume(Event event) {
        logger.info(String.format("Event created(from consumer)-> %s", event));
}
```

"event" is a json object which I am receiving as a message.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_max.poll.records:

> max.poll.records

> The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll().

> Type: int

> Default:  500

With Spring Boot you can configure it as this property:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.maxPollRecords
```

So, you set it to `1` and no more records are going to be polled from this consumer until you return from your `@KafkaListener` method.